# Can I get an ATPL if I have two drinking-and-driving offenses in the UK?

Tags: atpl

Can I get an ATPL if I have two drinking-and-driving offenses in the UK?
I am thinking of becoming a pilot and a would like to know if there is a possibility (of course, after a period of time, and of course a lot of training).

Comment: Now this is why regulations are a Good Thing in aviation.

Comment: why would any airline trust a repeat drink driver to fly for them? Or indeed to perform any function with any responsibility.

Comment: @jwenting If they can get a medical certificate saying they’re now sober (which usually includes monitoring to prove they’re staying sober), why not? They’re arguably less of a risk than pilots who still drink.

Comment: Alternatively, one might argue that their decision-making skills are not sound.

Comment: @StephenS, a medical certificate saying they’re now sober?  Do AMEs grant such a thing?

Comment: @MichaelHall That’s the entire point of the FAA’s HIMS program.

Comment: @StephenS, maybe expand that into an answer then?  I know the ask was specific to UK, but that would be good supplementary info.

Comment: @StephenS an addict will forever be a risk, I KNOW that alcoholism doesn't go away if you don't drink for a few weeks. My mother was an alcoholic, it was a struggle for the rest of her life to stay off the booze after we got her sober, and the only reason it worked at all was because she was completely dependent on us, being wheelchair bound, and couldn't get any more booze in the house. Was hell on my dad who missed his 1-2 glasses of cognac a week because of it, but better that than have mom drink the entire bottle in a few hours and want more...

Comment: @jwenting A few weeks? FAA HIMS requires a minimum of six months *proven* sobriety to reapply plus another six-plus months for them to process the paperwork, and the alcoholic/addict most continue random testing for as long as they continue flying. The resulting *lifetime* success rate is 88%. What you may know about other programs (such as AA/NA, which admit a *six-month* success rate of only 3%) does not apply.

Answer (score 7):

It's not the gaining of an ATPL that is the problem, so much as getting the medical certification to do so.

The UK CAA guidance material on alcohol/substance misuse can be found in [this pdf](https://www.caa.co.uk/media/scwpasth/alcohol-and-substance-misuse-fc-version-v4-1.pdf).

It basically states that any conviction for alcohol/substance misuse should be "Considered unfit" - this does NOT mean you will not be issued a Class 1 medical, the notes state

> If diagnosis, use or misuse is uncertain (e.g. first drink driving conviction and has had a clinical review by AME) fitness may be maintained
> after discussion with a Medical Assessor at the CAA. A 3rd party notification or allegation should be investigated - discussion with the individual/informer/AME/GP

So, like almost everything with aviation  medicals, the answer is to discuss it with an AME - certainly before commiting a large amount of time or money to flight training.